# Problem based on mean value theorem and intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:[0,8]\rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0, f(4)=1$ and $f(8)=1$, then there exists some $c \in (0,8)$ where $f'(c)=1/12$ We need to ascertain whether it is always true?

My approach using LMVT in [0,4] we can say there exists $c_1 \in (0,4)$ such that $f'(c_1)=\frac{1}{4}$ and using LMVT in [4,8] we can say there exists $c_2 \in (4,8)$ such that $f'(c_2)=0.$

Since $\frac{1}{12} \in (0,\frac{1}{4})$ using IVT we can say the statement is true. However, in the book answer is given statement is not always true. Please verify.

Comment: Your solution is correct although it is worth noting that the regular IVT requires $f'$ to be continuous (you are using what's called Darboux's theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is true. You correctly demonstrated that $f'$ takes the values $0$ and $1/4$. Also derivatives have the mean-value property (that is [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))), therefore $f'$ must take the value $1/12$ somewhere in the interval.

Note that one cannot apply the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) to $f'$ because the derivative need not be continuous.

Comment: Actually, what the OP did is not entirely correct (but what you did is), since the OP applied the Intermediate Value Theorem to solve the problem, which cannot be done without an extra hypothesis. (+1)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thanks – I was just about to add that information :)